# Trigger PointerEntered event only on non-transparent part of a .png image?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I want to add a mouse hover event in C# (creating a windows 8 app) on a irregular .png image that when its main image area (not the entire box or the transparent area) is hovered, its opacity should change.

Can I get a working code for this ?

Answer (score 0):

The alpha channel of a *PNG* has 256 levels. Where's the threshold? Total transparency or relative transparency? The latter also depends on color and the current background.

What I want to say is that a raster (per-pixel) approach might not yield the desired results.
In some cases it may be better to have a polygon describing the relevant area and check if the mouse position is inside or outside of that polygon.

This way the designer can exclude very faint areas he might redeem not relevant and, vice versa, include areas that would be otherwise excluded.

A compromise between these two approaches is the use of a collision mask that has just 1 bit per pixel and is `0` for *don't care* and `1` for *relevant*. That mask would be painted manually by the designer and used to detect if the pixel inside the *PNG* is relevant or not to the mouse.